# How to use Integrated Terminal Tool Window instead of external console Window for ASP.Net Core projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, integrated-terminal-window

In the ASP.Net Core projects development process by Visual Studio, an additional icon appears in the taskbar for the console window. This can be a little bit annoying during windows change by ALT+TAB combination (*I am a little bit obsessed*). Is it possible to use Integrated Terminal Tool for this necessity and keep the taskbar clean as possible?

Answer (score 6):

The feature came with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5 update.

> **Summary of What's New in this Release of Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5**
>
> **ASP.NET Output in the Integrated Terminal**
>
> • ASP.NET Core applications launched in Visual Studio now redirect output to the Integrated Terminal Tool Window instead of an external console Window.

It is possible to set it as Integrated Terminal under ASP.Net Core options.

- Open **Visual Studio**
- Select **Tools** Menu
- Then **Options** Selection
- Focus **Projects and Solutions**
- And then **ASP.NET Core**
- Next to **Run web server in**
- Choose **Integrated Terminal**
- Click **OK**

[image: Visual Studio Option Window]

**Preview**
[image: Preview]

Comment: Works in VS 2022 v17.8.6. It's a shame you can set the same setting for console apps as well. The only workaround I found for console apps is to set the SDK to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, which feels wrong.